# Sencha Touch Chart, visible in browser, but not in my android phone

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I trying to build an application using Sencha Touch 2.4.1,
and using cordova packager.

My simple application show chart, when i use 
"start sencha web start" application for browsing.

[image]
(picture 1).

But when i pack the app to android apk, 
on my android phone, it doesn't show the chart,
only starting animation..

[image]
(picture 2)

However if i remove line with xtype: 'companystockchart',
my application (on phone) is working (of course without chart)!

What am i doing wrong?

Source code:

app.js:

```
Ext.require([ 
              ]);

Ext.application({
    name: 'app',
    views: ['CompanyStockChart'],
    launch: function() {

    Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
                fullscreen: true,
            layout: 'fit',
            title: 'Chart',
            iconCls: 'overview',
            items:[{
                    xtype: 'companystockchart'
          }],
            listeners: {
                activate: function() {
                }
            }
        })

    }
});
```

app.view.CompanyStockChart.js:

```
Ext.define('app.view.CompanyStockChart', {
  extend: 'Ext.chart.Chart',
  alias: 'widget.companystockchart',
  config: {
        store: {
            fields: ['name', 'value'],
            data: [
                { name: 'Jan', value: 110},
                { name: 'Feb', value: 252},
                { name: 'Mar', value: 952},
                { name: 'Apr', value: 325},
                { name: 'May', value: 123},
                { name: 'Jun', value: 52},
                { name: 'Jul', value: 1122},
                { name: 'Aug', value: 35},
                { name: 'Sep', value: 172},
                { name: 'Oct', value: 752},
                { name: 'Nov', value: 810},
                { name: 'Dec', value: 410}
            ]
        },
        animate: false,
        interactions: ['panzoom'],
        series: [
            {
                type: 'line',
                xField: 'name',
                yField: 'value',
                style: {
                    fill: 'rgba(0,40,170,0.3)',
                    stroke: 'black'
                }
            }
        ],
        axes: [
            {
                type: 'numeric',
                position: 'left',
                title: 'Number of Hits',
                minimum: 0,
                maximum: 1200,
                grid: {
                    fill: '#efefef',
                    odd: {
                        fill: '#cdcdcd'
                    },
                    even: {
                        lineWidth: 3
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                type: 'category',
                position: 'bottom',
                title: 'Month of the Year',
                grid: true,
                style: {
                    estStepSize: 1
                }
            }
        ]

}

});
```

Next i try to debug the app, and i see next issue:

[image: (picture 3).]
(picture 3)

Comment: Have you already attached ADB and get a console output? That should give you an error message which can help to find your issue.

Comment: Yes i have, as you see in picture #3